# Proper Textbox that only allow numeric and decimal in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, textbox, decimal

I really need help in visual basic.

I have 3 textboxes that allow numeric and decimal with the code below:

```
If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)
                               AndAlso Not e.KeyChar = "." Then
    e.Handled = True
End If
```

But I have encountered few problems:

1. I can put "." anywhere
2. when I try to add with each textbox, the result is a mess. example 1.2 + 3 =15

Can you fix my code so it can make a proper decimal calculation?

Comment: Well that `"."c` looks wrong...

Comment: what's wrong with the "."c  ?

Comment: I have no idea what that c means. Does that mean that the dot should have the type char?

Comment: ah, yeah, so sry it's just "."

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful

```
   Private Sub txtrate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtmarks.KeyPress
            If InStr(txtmarks.Text, ".") Then
                e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            Else
                e.Handled = Not ((Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = ".") Or Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
            End If
    End Sub
```